# Systemd service run binary and after run script?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, scripts, systemd

I have the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Renews letsencrypt certificates
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/etc/letsencrypt/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/letsencrypt renew
```

And the following timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=letsencrypt timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
Persistent=true
Unit=letsencrypt.service

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

I have a bash script: `myscript.sh`

I'd like this to run after the `/usr/bin/letsencrypt renew` has finished and is wanting to exit (takes a few seconds). Is this possible?

Comment: This appears to be a near duplicate of question you recently asked on Serverfault also about how to run one Let's Encrypt command after another using systemd: http://serverfault.com/questions/836451/systemd-after-not-starting-service